# openpyxl(): Reading the cell value not the cell formula

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl() to copy the contents of an excel to another excel.

My original excel has an empty column in it, so i am not inserting the first column value and removing the empty column to the new file.

Because of this the formulas that was being used gets messed up.
Ex:
Original File:

```
A        B    C    D       E
(empty   1    2    3    =SUM(B1:D1)
column)
```

New File:

```
A    B    C       D       
1    2    3    =SUM(B1:D1)
```

So because of this my calculations in D column gets changed.

My code:

```
ORG_EXCEL_FILE = openpyxl.load_workbook("workbook.xlsx")
ORG_EXL_SHEET_NAMES = ORG_EXCEL_FILE.sheetnames

NEW_EXCEL_FILE = openpyxl.load_workbook("TEST.xlsx")
NEW_EXCEL_FILE_WS = NEW_EXCEL_FILE.active

ORG_FILE_SHEET = ORG_EXCEL_FILE.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
NEW_FILE_SHEET = NEW_EXCEL_FILE.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")          
            
for i,row in enumerate(ORG_FILE_SHEET.iter_rows()):
    for j,col in enumerate(row):
        NEW_FILE_SHEET.cell(row=i+1,column=j+1).value = col.value
        
NEW_EXCEL_FILE.save("TEST.xlsx")
```

When I run the above code the col.value and col.interval_value both gives the cell formula.

I tried using **openpyxl.load_workbook("workbook.xlsx", data_only=True)**, it gives me **None** for cell.value and cell.internal_value.

Is there a way to get the exact column value instead of the formula or None value ?

Thanks,

Comment: You can only get the value if some application has calculated it.

Comment: Well, i am not getting them even after the app calculated it

Comment: Can confirm that this only works if you open the file in Excel, save, and close. Even opening the file and seeing that the value has been recalculated correctly isn't enough (and it doesn't tell you there are changes that need saving).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're only missing a "data_only=True" when you load your workbook. Without loading with data_only, you'll be pulling the formula itself as the value, rather than the output of the formula.

```
ORG_EXCEL_FILE = openpyxl.load_workbook("workbook.xlsx", data_only=True)
ORG_EXL_SHEET_NAMES = ORG_EXCEL_FILE.sheetnames

NEW_EXCEL_FILE = openpyxl.load_workbook("TEST.xlsx", data_only=True)
NEW_EXCEL_FILE_WS = NEW_EXCEL_FILE.active

ORG_FILE_SHEET = ORG_EXCEL_FILE.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
NEW_FILE_SHEET = NEW_EXCEL_FILE.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")          
            
for i,row in enumerate(ORG_FILE_SHEET.iter_rows()):
    for j,col in enumerate(row):
        NEW_FILE_SHEET.cell(row=i+1,column=j+1).value = col.value
        
NEW_EXCEL_FILE.save("TEST.xlsx")
```